# How to override entity saving, in EFCore?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I want to store a List of objects in my model but I know EFCore doesn't support that. To work around it I have created a private string attribute on the model to hold the IDs of the objects in the list. My intention is to populate the list in the constructor of the class when it is restored. My class is as follows:

```
public class Visitor
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    private string _DepartmentIds { get; set; }

    public List<Department> Departments { get; set; }

    public Visitor()
    {
        if (_DepartmentIds.Length > 0)
        {
            Departments = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Department>>(_DepartmentIds);
        }
        else
        {
            Departments = new List<Department>();
        }
    }
}
```

I have two problems. One is that _DepartmentIds does not get saved / tracked by EFCore. I presume because it is private. The second is I need to create a method that will read the IDs from the department list to put them into the _DepartmentIds string but I don't know how to call this method on the object's saving. Is it possible to override or extend the entity model saving in EFCore?

*EDIT: I'm using deserialization rather than just concatenating IDs with a separator because I might want to expand this later.*

Comment: What do you mean mean by "I want to store a List of objects in my model but I know EFCore doesn't support that."? It's a basic 1-N relationship, it's fully supported.

Comment: Why don't you just create a new table like any relational database?

Comment: Sakuto. What I mean is that it wont save a List. I have to make a Many To Many relationship via a new intermediary joining class. I'd like to be able to just store the Ids in and repopulate the list as needed.

Comment: Camilo. I started to do that but it just seems more efficient for what I had in mind to be able to store the ids. In Django I'd be able to override the Save method so I assumed that would be possible here as well.

Answer (score 0):

For One:Many relationships, you should instead be creating a separate tables and joining them. The schema should be something like:

```
public class Visitor {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public List<Department> Departments { get; set; }
}

public class Department {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int VisitorID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(VisitorID))]
    public Visitor Visitor { get; set; }
}
```

If you don't want to have the `Visitor` object in `Department`, you could also configure it through the fluent API using something like:

```
entity.HasOne<Visitor>()
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(department => department.VisitorID);
```

When you perform lookups on `Visitor`, you will then be able to use the `Include` function to include all the related Departments.